# Where does TFS store source code, and how can I access it?

Tags: tfs

On my TFS server, how can I see where the source code (which folder) of my team project collection is stored?

I can't find anything specifying a location in the Administration Console.

Is the source stored on the file system?

**Edit:** Stupid question - got confused between TFS and VSS. TFS stores the source and changesets in a SQL database while VSS stores the source on the file system.

Comment: Just for your information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572535/how-and-where-does-tfs-2008-tfs-2010-store-changesets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will need to check out the code to be able to see it. TFS stores Changesets, not individual files.

Comment: ok but out of interest, it must store the source and changesets somewhere on the server? I was wondering where that location is - are the changesets just stored in the TFS installation folder?

Comment: Thanks, but could you please cite some reference in your answer? I would like to read more.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar question and that is how I ran into this thread but I knew that TFS stored data in a sql database but I wanted to know what table(s) because I wanted to make sure my setup was working correctly with friendly names that I had set up.  I did a little digging and the root changeset table is **`tbl_ChangeSet`** in your TFS database.  From there you can extrapolate what you need.  Hope that helps.