# Checking in pending changes in TFS does not affect source code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tfs

I'm an *extreme* newbie to managing TFS, so please bear with me and know I'll need baby steps.  I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I recently inherited an MVC ASP.net website written by a former colleague.  Generally he would work directly in the production environment and commit changes as he went along.  Obviously that's not good practice, so when I received it I decided to set it up in TFS along with a proper testing and development environment.  I created the team project collection, added the existing solution to the collection, set up branching and branch hierarchy, and mapped the work environments.  From what I can tell it's set up just like our other site that was configured in TFS before I came on (the person who set it up is long gone).

The issue I'm seeing now is that checking in changes don't seem to be affecting the actual code behind the site.  Whether I make the changes in the test branch and then check-in/merge changeset with the production branch, or make the changes directly in production, saving and checking in changes doesn't actually affect the site.  If I go into solution explorer and look at the files I just edited, my checked-in changes are not there. Same if I edit a web.config or something, I can then open in up in another text editor and my changes are nowhere to be found.

I followed Microsoft's instructions as closely as I could but clearly I missed something, I just have no idea what.

Comment: Have you deployed the code or did a get latest in your production environment? When you check in code, the changes are only stored in an SQL database. No actual files are changed in any other environment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572535/how-and-where-does-tfs-2008-tfs-2010-store-changesets

Comment: I always run a get latest before working on any files, but I was unaware of the need to deploy the code.  Our other site is apparently set up to automatically deploy changes when files are saved or checked in, so it never occurred to me.  

I appreciate you pointing me in this direction, as I was able to look up more information on deploying.  It appears I need to create a build controller in order to deploy?  What's odd is that a build controller is not configured for our other site, so now I'm left wondering wtf is making it work.

Comment: You're welcome. I can't speak to your environment, but in our TFS setup, we have TFS do a nightly build. This nightly build can export the files a normal build it creates to a folder of your choice. We manually deploy our files(copy and paste files to PRD) though. You can set up these builds to run on check in too. If you go to Team Explore, Create a new Build Definitions. Check out this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181286%28v=vs.90%29.aspx or read about TFSBuild.exe. It might be able to provide more help for you. Hope this is the info you are looking for.

Comment: So by pure accident I figured out it's due to the workspace settings.  I changed it from local workspace to server workspace in the project collection source control settings, now all saved or checked-in changes are showing in the solution and taking effect in the site.  Checked with our other web app that was already configured, sure enough that's the same workspace type it's running off.

Comment: Good to hear. Thank you for posting the solution as it might help me in the future too.